# Disable chrome react DevTools for production

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to browserify my react app for production using gulp and envify to setup NODE_ENV. So I can remove react warning, error reporting in the console, and even my code to disable some features like the require of react-addons-perf.

And it's working great. When I search in my app.js for "production" to see if there are theses typical conditions :

```
if("development" !== "production") {
    ...
}
```

There is nothing, so, as I said, it seems to work well.

But, I still can see that chrome's react DevTools tab with all react components, like if I was on a development website. **How can I disable this tab in chrome's dev tools ?**

Here is my gulp task :

```
var production  = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false;
var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'dev';

...

var bundler = browserify({
    debug: !production,

    // These options are just for Watchify
    cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true
})
.require(require.resolve('./dev/client/main.js'), { entry: true })
.transform(envify({global: true, _: 'purge', NODE_ENV: environment}), {global: true})
.transform(babelify)
.transform(reactify);

var start = Date.now();
bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
        this.emit("end");
    })
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulpif(options.uglify, streamify(uglify())))
    .pipe(gulpif(!options.debug, streamify(stripDebug())))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dest))
    .pipe(notify(function () {
        console.log('Built in ' + (Date.now() - start) + 'ms');
    }));
};
```

Comment: The actual plugin in Chrome? Why would you want to do that? Your js shouldn't contain anything sensitive. Why would Chrome allow you, from a website, to change things in Chrome? Think about it - that would be a massive security flaw, to be able to turn stuff on/off in the users browser with javascript.

Comment: Yeah, the chrome plugin.

Don't worry, the user can't do nothing if he is not authenticated : every request is checked with a token on the server side with a strong secret key (1024 char.).

My question is, is it possible and how ? As far as I know, it's possible do to it so here I am asking how and why it isn't working with my gulp task.

Comment: Ah I see, it won't work if there isn't a global `React` or `require`, but not sure about a specific setting

Comment: I recently published a package to disable the React Developer Tools plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fvilers/disable-react-devtools

Comment: If anyone is interested in bypassing this "protection" by any answers here or NPM packages, simply use the Local Overrides functionality in Chrome and delete the offending lines after beautifulcation. e.g. https://www.trysmudford.com/blog/chrome-local-overrides/

Answer (score 36):

According to an issue on Github, you can add run a single javascript line before react is loaded to prevent it.

From [#191 of react-devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/191)

```
<script>
window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function () {}
</script>
```

Then, you may consider wrapping this with your environment condition, like that you could do sth like below in your server side rendering. Let's say Pug (formerly known as Jade):

```
#{process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? "window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function(){}" : ""}
```

However, it would be still a good practice to put the business logic and the sensitive data back to your server.

Comment: I am getting following error : Cannot set property 'inject' of undefined

Comment: go to `chrome://extensions/` to see if the "React Developer Tools" is activated

Comment: @LoveTrivedi are you rendering this through the server? Remember Node doesn't have a window object. Wrap the snippet in 
`if (window){ ... }`

Comment: @LoveTrivedi That will probably happen if you don't have the react devtools installed. So, your code should probably check if `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` is even defined first.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `redux-devtools-extension` you can do this.

```
const devTools =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
    : composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, devTools);
```

This will make sure your devtools extension only works in the development environment and not in the production environment

Comment: This answer is referencing redux dev tools and not react-devtools.

Answer (score 6):

Just improve @peteriod answer, to make sure Dev tool has installed or not

```
if (typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'object') {
   __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function() {};
}
```

Comment: you can add it to index.html file in public folder.

Comment: How do we assign/access the environment variable inside the script tags? so that 
enable only in production mode.

Comment: @siluverukirankumar add this condition `"%NODE_ENV%" !== "development"`

Answer (score 2):

You could also delete all source map after build by adding the command below on your package.json file.

```
"scripts":{
     ...,
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "rimraf build/**/*.map"
}
```

It makes it a bit difficult to navigate the components and hides them on devtools - source

Answer (score 1):

you can check the mode :

---

add below code befor `</body>` in your **index.html** in the **public** folder

```
  <input type="hidden" value="%NODE_ENV%" id="node_env_mode" />
<script>
  var mode = document.querySelector("#node_env_mode").value;
  if (
    mode === "production" &&
    typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === "object"
  ) {
    window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function () {};
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's not a bulletproof idea - one could create a local proxy server that serves your website from localhost, fooling this mechanism.

Comment: @WojciechMaj you are right. I edited my answer to a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@fvilers/disable-react-devtools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fvilers/disable-react-devtools) package to disable React Developer tool

First, install the package mentioned above

```
npm i @fvilers/disable-react-devtools
```

or

```
yarn add @fvilers/disable-react-devtools
```

than

Call the `disableReactDevTools()` method before React is loaded, in your main file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { disableReactDevTools } from '@fvilers/disable-react-devtools';
import App from './App';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  disableReactDevTools();
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

for my solution that work with `npm run build`

1. add file `.env.production` to root project (same place with `package.json` file)
2. add properties `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=true` to file `.env.production` (recommend add with `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to make sure `*.map` file will not generated after build)
3. final try `npm run build` enjoy ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your store.js

```
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const devTools =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    : composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, devTools);

export default store;
```

Comment: OP asked about React DevTools. This answer concerns Redux DevTools. Not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the dev tools you have to remove the following line from the file **index.js**:

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
```

It is a line of index.js, i.e., of line **23**.

Comment: man re-read the article

Answer (score 0):

I always use a 'fvilers/disable-react-devtools' package and it has always worked for me.

All you need to do is install this page by using

```
npm i @fvilers/disable-react-devtools
```

and then tell your app you are in production env. Import the package into your app by

```
import { disableReactDevTools } from '@fvilers/disable-reactdevtools';
```

and then use the use the following code snippet on top of you app component.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  disableReactDevTools();
}
    import { disableReactDevTools } from '@fvilers/disable-react-devtools';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  disableReactDevTools();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution just worked for me perfectly, define the below function inside your root file then call the `disbaleReactDevTools()` function:

```
const disableReactDevTools = (): void => {
  const noop = (): void => undefined;
  const DEV_TOOLS = (window as any).__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__;

  if (typeof DEV_TOOLS === "object") {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(DEV_TOOLS)) {
      DEV_TOOLS[key] = typeof value === "function" ? noop : null;
    }
  }
};
```

you can find more details in here: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/191#issuecomment-443607190