# Minify React's Virtual DOM (not the code itself, but the output)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, minify

I understand there is no performance benefit to this, I am just looking to make code inspection the tiniest bit more of a pain. Is it possible to get React to output the virtual DOM in a compressed format? Thanks very much for any help you can offer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33783620/2479481

Comment: Not quite, but this is definitely interesting so thank you very much!

Comment: Then can you clarify with an example of what you're getting vs. what you want?

Comment: I would just like to remove all the whitespace in the virtual DOM react outputs pretty much.