# Is REACT State in Production visible in DevTools or something?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Can you See State variables in Production or are they private in the class and not viewable from outside?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **To view state, you will need to install [React's Devtool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)**

**Then open your developer tool then switch to the component tab:**

[image]

**Find and click to your component that has a state, then you will see your state also your props on the right side:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer of this question: [Disable chrome react DevTools for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783620/disable-chrome-react-devtools-for-production) you are able to disable the use of the react dev tools on your production site, however this would not absolutely stop the user from reading the state as they could always find & disable that line of code, or find some other way of accessing the state.

React runs entirely inside the user's browser, and because of this it is not possible to completely prevent the user from accessing the source code, or things like the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react devtools to inspect state and props of a component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check them via something like React dev tools.